# Guacamole common js - How to integrate microphone?

Tags: audio, web-audio-api, guacamole, guacamole-common.js

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76455664/how-to-access-microphone-in-guacamole-common-js] - This is not working for me.

I have created a custom web application using Guacamole common js to render and use virtual machine. But I couldnt redirec the microphone from the host machine to the VM connected via guacamole.

I tried providing the options

1. GUAC_AUDIO
2. enable-audio-input=true

Please let me know how to integrate microphone in guacamole common js

I trying to integrate microphone or sound input to be redirected to the virtual machine which is connected via guacamole common js